# How do I change 'LC_COLLATE' and 'LC_CTYPE' from an azure database for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, azure

I need to change these parameters from `English_United States.1252` to`Portuguese_Brazil.1252` does anyone know how to do? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `collate` and `ctype` parameters when you create database.

Please follow the [postgresql article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/multibyte.html) and try to execute below sql:

1.Create Encoding:

```
CREATE COLLATION "pb_PB.utf8" (lc_collate = 'Portuguese_Brazil', lc_ctype = 'Portuguese_Brazil');
```

2.Create DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE pb WITH ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE='Portuguese_Brazil' LC_CTYPE='Portuguese_Brazil' TEMPLATE=template0;
```

[image]

Or maybe you could refer to this case:

[Azure PostgreSQL Server Service Collation Create Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791728/azure-postgresql-server-service-collation-create-error)

Comment: I was able to create in `Brazilian`. But I'm still having an error when I'm coding the results of a query .. the bank is returning me an invalid character. `à`returns me -> `�` Thats generate a error in the json_encode = /